# Upgrading the ag-grid version from V.18.x.x to V.25.3.x in Angular application

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Angular application utilize ag-grid version 18.x.x and needs to be upgraded from ag-grid version V.18.x.x to V.25.3.x, there are few queries-

1. If the version upgrade could be done directly from 18.x.x to 25.3.x or it should happen in increments?
   what steps are required to do necessary changes

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is just to go for it and fix whatever breaks.  See the [changelog](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/) (especially the Breaking Changes checkbox) to see what has changed between those versions.

Be aware that the package name has now changed from ag-grid-community to @ag-grid-community/all-modules.

As to what steps are required for the changes.... it depends on how you've used the grid.  Give it a go and report back any issues.  Good luck!